# How to optimize rendering of many sphereGeometry in three.js?

Tags: javascript, optimization, three.js, webgl

I'd like to optimize the rendering of sphereGeometry in three.js, since it becomes bottleneck in my program. The javascript program is shown as follows:

```
var sphereThree = [];
for(var idSphere = 0; idSphere < numSphere; idSphere++){
    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.0);
    var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});

    sphereThree[idSphere] = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);

    sphereThree[idSphere].position.x = x[idSphere];
    sphereThree[idSphere].position.y = y[idSphere];
    sphereThree[idSphere].position.z = z[idSphere];

    scene.add(sphereThree[idSphere]);
}
```

As mentioned in the folloing links:
[- Animateing a Million Letters Using Three.js](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/)
[- Optimizing Three.js Performance: Simulating Tens of Thousands of Independent Moving Objects](http://www.ianww.com/blog/2012/11/04/optimizing-three-dot-js-performance-simulating-tens-of-thousands-of-independent-moving-objects/)
they pointed out that we should not add object individually, and better add same kind of objects at the same time, for the optimization. However, since I'm new in this field, I have no idea how to code this optimization, when using SphereGeometry.

If somebody knows how to code these with using SphereGeometry, or somebody who knows a efficient method to render many (10,000 or more) spheres, would you teach us?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just reuse the geometry and material like this:

```
var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.0);
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});

var sphereThree = [];
for(var idSphere = 0; idSphere < numSphere; idSphere++){
    sphereThree[idSphere] = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);

    sphereThree[idSphere].position.x = x[idSphere];
    sphereThree[idSphere].position.y = y[idSphere];
    sphereThree[idSphere].position.z = z[idSphere];

    scene.add(sphereThree[idSphere]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! It worked, and the rendering time becomes 4.5 times faster, for 2000 particles case!! By the way, this method is only applicable when the particle's color and size is same. Do you know how to speed up the rendering time when each particle properties are different?

Comment: Make one `sphereGeometry` but make multiple `sphereMaterials` to change the color. As for size set the scale with `sphereThree[idSphere].scale.x = sphereThree[idSphere].scale.y = sphereThree[idSphere].scale.z = scale` ?

Comment: Thanks, gman! The idea you suggested allow us to render different sizes of spheres without increasing the time. However, the multiple `sphereMaterials` increased the rendering time in my application. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Moved ONE variable to a global position -- "var texture1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/concrete.jpg" );" -- and the difference was night and day. Thanks, mrdoob!

Comment: @mrdoob, 

As you mentioned i have created some geometry and applied matrix for each mesh, 
mesh.applyMatrix(matrix4) work charm, but intersection not happening, 
do i need to create multiple geometry and apply matrix to geometry, 
if so then rendering time and memory taken to render wont increase?

Comment: Achieved a profound performance improvement by doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If appearance of the spheres does not matter a lot, you can also set widthSegments and heightSegments parameters to values lower than the defaults.
See documentation [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/SphereGeometry).

Essentially do something like:

```
var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.0, 5, 4);
```

**Update**
I forgot to mention that this should be done once you try mrdoob's suggestion and you want to optimize further. The speedup is not significant.

Comment: Thank you for answering!! Though I've tried your idea, it was not efficient for my code. The rendering time become a bit faster, however the other computation, which determines the collision of spheres, becomes heavier somehow.

Comment: @eng27 you are right that it is not a great improvement, but how did you measure the collision detection runtime. There are less faces so it should be faster. Unless it is optimized for the default number of faces, I will update again my answer after checking that.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I consider the sphere as a "ideal" sphere, since I am using it to render the result of physical simulation. Therefore, the number of faces is not a big matter when computing the collision. However, the computational time increases somehow.

Comment: I believe you use your own method. Is the difference observable in every run? Always allow a room for error in measurements. I hope you don't use a tool like chrome developer tools to claim that. It measures percentage of time and not absolute values so if one method's percentage decreases the other's increases.